# Can't get the liferay login user details in portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I have one proxy portlet and one Generic portlet. Here I am sending Post data from proxy portlet to generic portlet. While sending the data I use post method and sending to the view.jsp page. In view.jsp I am able to get the form data through input stream. Now the issue is I need to get the login user details in the generic portlet, If I run my generic portlet separately I am able to get the user details. But I call the view.jsp from proxy portlet I am not able to get the user details. May be the generic portlet is not initialized If I call view.jsp from proxy porlet so it is throwing the following error,

```
9 Mar, 2015 8:35:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Producer-portlet] threw exception
 [An exception occurred processing JSP page /html/jsp/view.jsp at line 71

68: %>
69:
70: <%
71:  String fullname= user.getFullName();
72:  System.out.println("Full name is: "+fullname);
73:  %>
74:


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.html.jsp.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:254)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:116)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:
67)
        at $Proxy646.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(Invo
kerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilte
r.java:74)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(Invo
kerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:
67)
        at $Proxy646.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFil
ter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilte
r.java:74)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(Invo
kerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.ja
va:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:102
3)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.jav
a:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My `view.jsp` code is,

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<theme:defineObjects />
 <%
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (request.getInputStream());
     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int value;
        while ((value=in.read()) != -1) {
            buffer.append((char)value);
          }
      String formData =  buffer.toString();
%>
<%
 String fullname= user.getFullName();
 System.out.println("Full name is: "+fullname);
 %>
<h1>Welcome to Liferay MVC Employee Portlet</h1>
```

How can I get the login user details If I call my `view.jsp` from proxy portlet?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the last sentence, "...if I call my view.jsp from proxy portlet"?

Comment: In my proxy portlet, I am sending the form data with following code, send(uri = "http://localhost:9090/Producer-portlet/html/jsp/view.jsp", method="POST", content="xml")

Comment: If the above line got executed, then control will come to view.jsp. But the user details are not able to get in view.jsp If I didn't invoke portlet properly. So How can I invoke the portlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you lose control over in the portlet world is your URLs. If you request your jsp files through servlet requests (like you mention in the comments to your question), you'll have a servlet request that obviously bypasses the portal (portal requests would be generated through `<portlet:actionURL .../>` or `<portlet:renderURL .../>`)

Thus, the approach that you mention is completely wrong in the portal world. You may go through `<portlet:resourceURL .../>` and utilize the resource phase of your portlet. However, for maintainability reasons I consider it bad practice to address one portlet from the view of another and would rather recommend to totally reconsider the architecture.

As I don't fully understand the underlying problem, I can't give a recommendation what to change the architecture to though.